# Google Map not loaded in tabs in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I have used [angular-google-map](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) in my angular4 application. On my application I have a component with two tabs, let's say tab A and B, and I need to load maps on each tab. But tab B does not show the map.

Component.html:-

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
 <div class="tab-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active">
        <a href="#tabA" data-toggle="tab">Tab A</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#tabB" data-toggle="tab">Tab B</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabA">
        <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
           <agm-polygon [paths]="Points"  [editable]=editable  [visible]="visible" [draggable]=draggable [fillColor]=fillColor>
           </agm-polygon>
        </agm-map>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tabB">
        <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
           <agm-polygon [paths]="Points2"  [editable]=editable  [visible]="visible" [draggable]=draggable [fillColor]=fillColor>
           </agm-polygon>
        </agm-map>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Component.ts:-

```
lat          : any = 33.5362475;
lng          : any = -111.9267386;
zoom         : any = 10;
fillColor    : any = '#DC143C';
draggable    : any = true;
editable     : any = true;
visible      : any = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize() the google map. You can do it like this:

```
@ViewChild('agmMap') agmMap : AgmMap;

tabActivated() {
        this.agmMap.triggerResize();
    }
```